# Messages marked as spam by Facebook Chat API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm developing a smartphone application that allows the user to login with facebook and then send a message to his friends using the Facebook Chat API.

To achieve that I send the facebook access token to my server and then use it in PHP to send the message on the user behalf using the Facebook API with xmpp_login permission which the user already granted.

The process works and the message is sent and received correctly. However when the conversation is reopened those messages are not shown anymore but instead a text telling "This message is no longer available because it was identified as abusive or marked as spam" is shown.

Somebody could help me in finding out why that's happening? I also tried to create another facebook app to test out if for some reason my app was added to some spam list but that's doesn't seem to be the case since also for the new one the behaviour is the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: same here on Android...

Answer (score 2):

Change the Sandbox mode to off in your app! I had the same problem and worked for me.